# Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC grid datasource filters value is null

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to dynamically add grid filters in my view using the html helper via datasource configuration, like this example  from the [kendo documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
        .Filter(filters =>
        {
            if (someCondition){
               // Show products whose ProductName property contains "C"
               filters.Add(product => product.ProductName).Contains("C");
               // and UnitsInStock is greater than 10
               filters.Add(product => product.UnitsInStock).IsGreaterThan(10);
            }
        })
    )
)
```

The filters are added, but the filterdescriptor.Value in each case is always null (the Member and Operator are fine).

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks!
--Berry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have included kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js. Missing it would lead to similar symptoms.

Comment: I have that file, but it's this version:
     `* Kendo UI Complete v2012.2.913`
Is this supported in this version, or do I need to upgrade to latest?

Comment: I upgraded my reference to Kendo.MVC.dll version 2013.1.514.340, and that resolved the issue.

Comment: +1 Wow, thank you very much! At the beginning of the project, I added the 'Kendo.all.js' file in my project and I excluded the possibility of having to add another javascript file considering the size of 'Kendo.all.js'. The paging work even if you have 'kendo.aspnetmvc' but not the others parameters.